# Error: The type name 'xxx' does not exist in the type

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have strange error, which happens only when i copy and when i am using the project only in my home laptop. It all works fine in the original office laptop in Windows 7 but when i copy that entire project into a home laptop running on windows 8 it says following error

I am using Windows 8 with Visual Studio 2005 version. I have read the Official guide for this error

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sy234eat.aspx

but none of these apply because it works fine in the office computer running win 7.

```
The type name 'Utility' does not exist in the type 'OE.WebUI.OO'    
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\oo\OE.WebUI\Controls\Item.ascx.designer.cs   19  31  OE.WebUI
```

coding is as below,

```
namespace OE.WebUI.Controls {

public partial class ItemShopp {

protected OE.Utility.Logic.Equal IndOrder;
```

this same project works fine in the office, but if i copy everything into my home laptop and change simple "space" it gives me the above error. Do you guys have any idea ? is this a path problem or Windows 8 problem ?

Comment: Is `Utility` defined in your code or externally?

Comment: Is `Utility` actually there?

Comment: Have you copied all starting from `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\oo`? Have you tried clean/rebuild?

Comment: it's possible that non-startup projects related to the solution must be built beforehand or dll's registered / copied. Something is bound to be missing on your notebook, most probably from the bin folder. Compare those.

Comment: yes, utility files all there, utility is defined as custom library class, yes i have tried clean rebuild..

Answer (score 0):

the windows 8 may not be having the dll for the library that you are using. to resolve this issue do the following in your office laptop and then copy the project in your home laptop:

1- In your solution explorer, find the reference library that is causing problem.

2- Open its properties and locate the property 'Copy local' and set it to true.

3- Build your project and copy it to home laptop with win 8 .

I hope your problem would be solved :)